# C: sys/queue.h - how to pass a pointer to TAILQ_HEAD() into a function, instead of having TAILQ_HEAD() be global?

Tags: c, queue

Pretty new to C here. I'm using `sys/queue.h` to make a simple queue. I've searched quite a bit on SO and Google and cannot find a solution to this particular question.

This works fine:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/queue.h> 

TAILQ_HEAD(, q_item) head;

typedef struct q_item {
        int value;
        TAILQ_ENTRY(q_item) entries;
} q_item;

void enqueue(int n) {
    // enqueue the node with value n
    q_item *item;
    item = malloc(sizeof(q_item));
    item->value = n;
    printf("queued %d\n", item->value);
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&head, item, entries);
}

void dequeue() {
    q_item *returned_item;
    returned_item = TAILQ_FIRST(&head);
    printf("dequeued %d\n", returned_item->value);
    TAILQ_REMOVE(&head, returned_item, entries);
    free(returned_item);
}

int main() {

    TAILQ_INIT(&head);

    enqueue(1);
    enqueue(2);
    enqueue(3);

    dequeue();

    return 0;
}
```

I know in general global variables should be avoided. Though I also know TAILQ_HEAD() is a macro, so maybe that changes how I should think about this. Anyway, this doesn't compile:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/queue.h> 

typedef struct q_item {
        int value;
        TAILQ_ENTRY(q_item) entries;
} q_item;

void enqueue(int n, TAILQ_HEAD(, q_item) * head) {
    // enqueue the node with value n
    q_item *item;
    item = malloc(sizeof(q_item));
    item->value = n;
    printf("queued %d\n", item->value);
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(head, item, entries);
}

void dequeue(TAILQ_HEAD(, q_item) * head) {
    q_item *returned_item;
    returned_item = TAILQ_FIRST(head);
    printf("dequeued %d\n", returned_item->value);
    TAILQ_REMOVE(head, returned_item, entries);
    free(returned_item);
}

int main() {

    TAILQ_HEAD(, q_item) head; // <-- I've moved TAILQ_HEAD into main()
    TAILQ_INIT(&head);

    enqueue(1, &head);
    enqueue(2, &head);
    enqueue(3, &head);

    dequeue(&head);

    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the latter I get the following errors. They are unhelpful since I cannot tell the difference between `‘struct <anonymous> *’` and `‘struct <anonymous> *’`.

```
test_tailq_noglobal.c:32:13: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘enqueue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
      enqueue(1, &head);
                 ^
test_tailq_noglobal.c:10:6: note: expected ‘struct <anonymous> *’ but argument is of type ‘struct <anonymous> *’
     void enqueue(int n, TAILQ_HEAD(, q_item) * head) {
      ^~~~~~~
```

I know the man page for TAILQ_HEAD shows that you can define the following:

```
TAILQ_HEAD(tailhead, entry) head;
struct tailhead *headp;                 /* Tail queue head. */
```

But I am not sure what to do with this `struct tailhead *headp`. I have tried passing it as a pointer in place of `&head` as follows, but this does not seem to work either:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/queue.h> 

typedef struct q_item {
        int value;
        TAILQ_ENTRY(q_item) entries;
} q_item;

void enqueue(int n, struct headname *headp) {
    // enqueue the node with value n
    q_item *item;
    item = malloc(sizeof(q_item));
    item->value = n;
    printf("queued %d\n", item->value);
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(headp, item, entries);
}

void dequeue(struct headname *headp) {
    q_item *returned_item;
    returned_item = TAILQ_FIRST(headp);
    printf("dequeued %d\n", returned_item->value);
    TAILQ_REMOVE(headp, returned_item, entries);
    free(returned_item);
}

int main() {

    TAILQ_HEAD(headname, q_item) head;
    struct headname *headp;
    TAILQ_INIT(headp);

    enqueue(1, headp);
    enqueue(2, headp);
    enqueue(3, headp);

    dequeue(headp);

    return 0;
}
```

Errors:

```
test_tailq_headp.c: In function ‘dequeue’:
test_tailq_headp.c:21:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct headname’
  returned_item = TAILQ_FIRST(headp);
                  ^
test_tailq_headp.c: In function ‘main’:
test_tailq_headp.c:33:13: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘enqueue’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  enqueue(1, headp);
             ^~~~~
test_tailq_headp.c:10:6: note: expected ‘struct headname *’ but argument is of type ‘struct headname *’
 void enqueue(int n, struct headname *headp) {
      ^~~~~~~
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, either in my code or in the way I'm thinking about this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Is this in Linux ? Also I mean is `sys/queue.h` related in Linux ? Can I find it in Windows ?

Answer (score 3):

I never work with this queue but one way I found is add TAILQ_HEAD() inside q_item itself. Its help to avoid global usage of head.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/queue.h>

typedef struct q_item {
    int value;
    TAILQ_ENTRY(q_item) entries;
    TAILQ_HEAD(, q_item) head;
} q_item;

void enqueue(int n, q_item *q) {
    // enqueue the node with value n
    q_item *item;
    item = malloc(sizeof(q_item));
    item->value = n;
    printf("queued %d\n", item->value);
    TAILQ_INSERT_TAIL(&q->head, item, entries);
}

void dequeue(q_item *q) {
    q_item *returned_item;
    returned_item = TAILQ_FIRST(&q->head);
    printf("dequeued %d\n", returned_item->value);
    TAILQ_REMOVE(&q->head, returned_item, entries);
    free(returned_item);
}

int main() {

    q_item q;
    TAILQ_INIT(&q.head);

    enqueue(1, &q);
    enqueue(2, &q);
    enqueue(3, &q);

    dequeue(&q);
    dequeue(&q);

    return 0;
}
```

Also it may be useful to look how this macros expand, just compile with `gcc` using `-E` option, and you will see that for example `TAILQ_HEAD(, qitem) head` expand  to

```
struct {
       struct q_item *tqh_first; 
       struct q_item **tqh_last; 
 } head;
```

Also you can find it in `<sys/queue.h>` [header](http://unix.superglobalmegacorp.com/xnu/newsrc/bsd/sys/queue.h.html)

```
/*
 * Tail queue definitions.
 */
#define TAILQ_HEAD(name, type)                                  \
struct name {                                                   \
    struct type *tqh_first; /* first element */                 \
    struct type **tqh_last; /* addr of last next element */     \
}
```

that's why your try with `void enqueue(int n, TAILQ_HEAD(, q_item) * head)` didn't work because preprocessor makes simple substituion.